# Woocommerce: Ajax add to cart not working inside WP Bakery page builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have solution build to add ajax add to cart functional to add to cart button in woocommerce single product page with variable product type.

It is working fine with single product page, when clicking on add to cart, it does add product to cart but on same time it does load popup window with 2 buttons, continue shopping and go to checkout.

Issue is, i am using porto theme and it allow to replace the single product page which i have created using WP Bakery page builder which consist of product title, descript and add to cart button. It does work fine and looks same as well when try to inspect element, so not sure why script is not being applied to it. I have posted all code below including the button added from inside the wp bakery page builder into single page.

```
<form class="variations_form cart vf_init" action="https://digitalcloud.no/en/product/product-test-1/" method="post" current-image="">
    
            <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="pa_storlek">Storlek</label></td>
                        
                            <td class="value">
                                <select id="pa_storlek" class="" name="attribute_pa_storlek" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_storlek" data-show_option_none="yes"><option value="">Choose an option</option><option value="10kg" class="attached enabled">10kg</option><option value="11kg" class="attached enabled">11kg</option><option value="12kg" class="attached enabled">12kg</option><option value="13kg" class="attached enabled">13kg</option><option value="15kg" class="attached enabled">15kg</option><option value="16kg" class="attached enabled">16kg</option><option value="17kg" class="attached enabled">17kg</option><option value="18kg" class="attached enabled">18kg</option><option value="19kg" class="attached enabled">19kg</option><option value="20kg" class="attached enabled">20kg</option><option value="21kg" class="attached enabled">21kg</option><option value="22kg" class="attached enabled">22kg</option><option value="23kg" class="attached enabled">23kg</option><option value="24kg" class="attached enabled">24kg</option><option value="25kg" class="attached enabled">25kg</option><option value="26kg" class="attached enabled">26kg</option><option value="27kg" class="attached enabled">27kg</option><option value="28kg" class="attached enabled">28kg</option><option value="2kg" class="attached enabled">2kg</option><option value="6kg" class="attached enabled">6kg</option><option value="9kg" class="attached enabled">9kg</option></select><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: visible;">Clear</a>                         </td>
                                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
        </table>

                <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            
            
                <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description"></div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>93,440.00</bdi></span></span></div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability"></div>
</div><div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">
    
        <div class="quantity buttons_added"><button type="button" value="-" class="minus">-</button>
                <input type="number" id="quantity_608ecccab62ec" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
            <button type="button" value="+" class="plus">+</button></div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>

    
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="112">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="112">
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="126">
</div>

            
                    </div>
        
    
    </form>
```

Here is the JS code

```
jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).addClass('adding-cart');
    var product_id = jQuery('input[name="product_id"]').val();
    var variation_id = jQuery('input[name="variation_id"]').val();
    var quantity = jQuery('input[name="quantity"]').val();
    //alert(variation_id);   
    jQuery('.cart-dropdown-inner').empty();
    if (variation_id==0) { 
        swal({
            title: 'Select a product variation',
        //  buttons: "CONTINEU SHOPPING",
            showCancelButton: false,
            showConfirmButton: true
        });

    } else {
    if (variation_id) {
        var product_id = jQuery('input[name="product_id"]').val();
        jQuery.ajax ({
            url: devops_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type:'POST',
            data:'action=devops_add_cart_single&product_id=' + product_id + '&variation_id=' + variation_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            success:function(results) {  
                //console.log(results);
                  if(results) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                        type : 'post',
                        data : {
                            'action': 'ajax_update_mini_cart'
                        },
                        success : function( response ) {
                            jQuery('.widget_shopping_cart_content').html(response);
                            jQuery('.cart-items').html(jQuery('.m-count').text());
                        }
                    });
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Product is added to cart !',
                        icon: 'success',
                        showDenyButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: `Continue shopping`,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#000000', 
                        denyButtonText: `Go to checkout`,
                        showCloseButton: true,
                      }).then((result) => {
                        /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                         if (result.isDenied) {
                            window.location.href = 'checkout/';
                        }
                      })
                           
                    } else {
                        /*Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Oops...',
                            text: 'Something went wrong!',
                            footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
                          })*/
                  }
            }

        });

    } else {
        var product_id = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.ajax ({
            url: devops_ajax_object.ajax_url,  
            type:'POST',
            data:'action=devops_add_cart_single&product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
            success:function(results) { 
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                    type : 'post',
                    data : {
                        'action': 'ajax_update_mini_cart'
                    },
                    success : function( response ) {
                        jQuery('.widget_shopping_cart_content').html(response);
                        jQuery('.cart-items').html(jQuery('.m-count').text());

                    }
                });

                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Product is added to cart !',
                    icon: 'success',
                    showDenyButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: `Continue shopping`,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#000000', 
                    denyButtonText: `Go to checkout`,
                    showCloseButton: true,
                  }).then((result) => {
                    /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                    if (result.isDenied) {
                        window.location.href = 'checkout/';
                    }
                })
            }
        });

    }
}

});
```

and here is the functions.php code

```
function devops_scripts() {
    if (is_singular('product')) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'devops-single', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/add-to-cart-shop.js', array('jquery'), date("h:i:s"), true );
        wp_localize_script( 'devops-single', 'devops_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'devops_scripts' );

function devops_add_cart_single_ajax() {
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $_POST['variation_id'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    if ($variation_id) {
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id );
    } else {
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity);
    }    

    echo '1';
}

add_action('wp_ajax_devops_add_cart_single', 'devops_add_cart_single_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_devops_add_cart_single', 'devops_add_cart_single_ajax');

function custom_enqueue(){
    //wp_enqueue_script('customstyle', 'https://digitalcloud.no/wp-content/themes/porto/js/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', 'https://digitalcloud.no/wp-content/themes/porto/js/sweetalert/sweetalert2.all.min.js', array(), '', 'all' );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue');

function ajax_update_mini_cart() {
    echo wc_get_template( 'cart/mini-cart.php' );
    die();
  }
  add_filter( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_update_mini_cart', 'ajax_update_mini_cart' );
  add_filter( 'wp_ajax_ajax_update_mini_cart', 'ajax_update_mini_cart' );
```